# Delete Duplicate Rows from Table based multiple Columns check and Table size remains same

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

[image: Table has been created with Header from B63:V1562]
In my Workbook, I have Table named as "MyTable" and it has ranges from B63:V1562. (1500 Rows Max)

**I would like to compare the Column B,C,G and H. If these column values are identical or Duplicate with other rows, I would like to clear the contents of those rows and fill with next valid row values.**

The concern over here as, Column L,M and V is having the Formulas. It should not get disturbed due to removal of this duplicates. All Columns having proper mapping with each other column of Data.

**Table size also should remain same.**

Please help me to figure out the solution for the same.

Thank you so much for your time and Valuable Responses.

Comment: Clear contents, instead of deleting rows?

Comment: @BigBen... Yeah That also great, But if we clearing the content then there will be more empty rows in between right? If there are no empty rows in between then it will be great help for me. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the function for Remove Duplicates and after that i am updating the Table back to it's normal size with the help of pre-defined arguments.

This code is working fine for me.

```
            Function RemoveDuplicates(ws As Worksheet, FindHeaderValue As Long, TableLength As Long)

            Dim TblRng As Range
            Dim objListObj As ListObject

            Set TblRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").Range
            TblRng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 6, 7), Header:=xlYes

            Set objListObj = ws.ListObjects("myTable")
            objListObj.Resize Range("B" & FindHeaderValue & ":V" & TableLength)
            End Function
```